# Use of readline function with Python StringIO module

Tags: python, encoding, ftp, newline, stringio

I am trying to read a file from an FTP site and process one line at a time.  I write from the FTP server to a StringIO object and call the readline function, but this returns the entire file, rather that the first line.  I downloaded the file to my pc and examined it with a hex editor, and the file uses x0d0a for a newline character, or a carriage return with a line feed.  Could somebody point out to me where I might be going wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import ftplib
import StringIO
settles = StringIO.StringIO()
ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.cmegroup.com')   
ftp.login() 
ftp.cwd('pub/settle/')             
ftp.retrlines('RETR cbt.settle.s.txt', settles.write) 
settles.seek(0)
print settles.readline()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [`FTP.retrlines` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrlines):

> ... The callback function is called for each line with a string argument containing the line with the trailing **CRLF stripped**.  ....

Replace `retrlines` with [`retrbinary`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrbinary).

Alternatively, you can `..retrlines ..` lines as follow (appending newlines):

```
ftp.retrlines('RETR cbt.settle.s.txt', lambda line: settles.write(line + '\n'))
```